# How to change dynamically the order of a barChart?

Tags: dc.js

I have a bar chart displaying countries. By default the ordering is by the name, but I would like to let the user dynamically switch to order by value

so I tried to

```
graph.ordering(function(d){ return +d.value }).render();
```

but it doesn't seem to be working for bar charts...**but it works fine for row charts for instance**

Is there a way to force the bar charts to use the ordering function after it's been rendered the first time? I tried to debug but didn't see something obvious

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't work - it seems to work for a redraw in [these transition tests](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/transitions/ordinal-bar-transitions.html). This is a chart with an ordinal x scale right?

Comment: yes. I will try to make a minimal test